# Why does the docker container exits immediately? on PLC

Tags: linux, docker, node-red, wago

I am running docker on a WAGO-PFC 8204 device and successfully able to install an image for node-red flow based editor. However, when i am trying to run the image, it creates a container but automatically exits. I am not running this image on a linux machine itself but instead of other device. I ran docker logs [container name] but output was  `Error: fatal error, line 0.` Please see the image attached.

Please help anyone if you can. Thanks

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text, they are really hard to read and impossible for people that use screen readers or to search for. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73028520/edit) the question and paste in the actual text then format it with the toolbar.

Comment: That PNG file is not runnable, and the error message you quote doesn't especially say anything.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What sort of device are you actually running it on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because version 3.0.0 of the Node-RED Docker container will not run on old versions of Docker that do not support 64bit time on a 32bit OS.

You can try adding `--security-opt=seccomp=unconfined` to the `docker run` command or upgrade docker/libseccom to a supported version of the latest apline base container.

Details of the minimum version are in the release notes on github

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.13.0#time64_requirements

https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/issues/319

Work around:

Use the nodered/node-red:2.2.2 container rather than the new 3.0.0 (latest) tags